# Magento getPost empty array

Tags: magento, http-post

I have the following code (please excuse the bad coding, it's like that to debug):

```
$postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
if(!$postData)
{
    $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost(); 
}
if(!$postData)
{
    $postData = $_POST; 
}
```

As you can see, I am simply trying to get the HTTP POST values.

Here's the scenario:

1. From a HTTP POST Simulator, the data comes through
2. From the Shopify webhook, nothing comes through (just "Array()")
3. Shopify posting to PostCatcher shows a lot of data

Shopify is posting in JSON format.

Any ideas as to ahy I can't catch the POST array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant get `JSON` post values by using simply `$_POST` or `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();`. Just try this,

```
$value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
print_r($value);
```

Answer (score 3):

In one of my project I got the same error

`Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();` was giving the blank values.

I was using one extension when I was submitting the form there was one description field for the manufacturer.

If it was having text content like **from** ,  **select** or some content similar to SQL commands.
It was not posting the form data.

The reason was the hosting provider had some settings for sanitizing the data to prevent the SQL injection.

I raised the ticket to the hosting provider and the problem was solved.

Before this I tried lot of coding stuff which was not required.

Answer (score 1):

Basically 
`Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();` and `$this->getRequest()->getPost();` are the same if you are in a controller.
They are also the same thing with `$_POST` with some additional filtering on the values.
So if you receive an empty array in any case you should receive an empty array for all cases.
Make sure the data is sent through POST.
Also try to see how `$this->getRequest()->getParams()` look like. Maybe Magento considers that the parameters are sent through `_GET`

Comment: could it be a server related issue? even $_GET is empty and this is in core module, in fact everything on the admin i try to save, doesn't get save.